# Execute VB Script on page_load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, registerstartupscript

I am having VB Script in ASPX page.I need to use that Script in codeBehind in Page _load with in a For loop,for each iteration.

My Code is :- 
(.ASPX Page with VB Script. )

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="vbscript" >
sub wordit()
'Opens Word application and does some process   
end sub
</script>
```

VB Code Behind Part:-

```
          For i As Integer = 1 To colSelRowIndex

            CheckboxTemplateId = colSelRowKeys(i).ToString 'I get the ID from here 
            ViewState("TemplateID") = CheckboxTemplateId 'I need to send the value to the sub routines 
            hen()'sub
            den()'sub
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1 & i, "wordit();", True)
        Next
```

I need to open a word doc for an ID and another document for another ID from the loop.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call MsgBox? You are aware that this will attempt to open a message on the web **server**, right? It won't open in the web browser.

Comment: @ joel-I need to be able to open the msgbox 10 times as i execute. but, now i can only get one msg box as the script registerstartup will just register the script and exit.is there any other alternative to call the script from codebehind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1 & i, "wordit();", True) 
Next
```

That second argument in that function call is looking for a unique key. This is a feature, to prevent accidentally programmatically adding the same script more than once. If you want to do it on purpose, you need a unique key each time.

But that you want to do this at all indicates a possible fundamental misunderstanding about what's going on. While your server code (including Page_Load) is running, your client page in the web browser **doesn't exist.** The purpose of the server code is *always* to generate an html response to web request. The server code can *never* directly manipulate a page DOM.

Obviously this is true for a first request to a page in session: the server must first generate the initial page to send the client. But even on subsequent postbacks, the browser will **destroy** the prior instance of a page. The server must rebuild the entire page from scratch. *Every. Time.* While this happens, the page you're looking at in your browser window is only a sort of after-image. The browser has already *destroyed* any prior DOM, and is waiting for the server to supply a whole new set of HTML.

I also wonder at your use of vbscript, rather than javascript. Using vbscript pretty much guarantees you're page will only work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: .I just have another quick question.In my actual code 

     For i As Integer = 1 To colSelRowIndex 
     CheckboxTemplateId =  colSelRowKeys(i).ToString ViewState("TemplateID") = CheckboxTemplateId hen() den() cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1 & i, "wordit();", True) Next

Comment: @user2526236 You can't force a word document to open. All you can do is download it to the client. There isn't really a way to get around this.

Comment: @ joel.I am able to open the document.that is the last document in which the loop exits.but,i need to do it for each and every ID

Comment: @user2526236 Always two there are: no more, no less; a **request** and a **response**. Loading/downloading a document is a _response_. Each response first needs its own _request_. If you want to download a group of documents, you'll need to zip (or similar) them up

Comment: @ Joel - IS there any other way instead of using RegisterStartupScript to call the script using a Sub Routine or a Function .

Comment: Have you been paying attention?